# How to get producer/consumer information from Azure Service Bus queue message?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-queues

I have one service who is sending messages to the queue and another which receive the messages, but it seems that this services are duplicated. The services that I´m aware of are deployed in Kubernetes, but the others I don´t know where are running.
So my question is, can I get some information from Azure that can help me to identify this other sources?

I did look into Azure Portal but didn´t find anything useful.
I'd like to get some information from Azure that can help me to identify this other sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** way to know the details of which service or program pushed a message into the ASB queue.

When the message was inserted into the queue, if the sender inserts some custom properties [via the `ApplicationProperties` of the `ServiceBusMessage` object], that can be used to identify the sender of the message. However, that defeats the purpose of using ASB queues - which is to **decouple** the components or services in your architecture. You shouldn't be doing it.